# Not getting updates from update manager ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager

I am not getting any updates since 2 weeks. Whenever i open the update manager it shows that the computer is up to date. When i try to run update manager through the terminal i get these errors:

```
(update-manager:5052): Glib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed

(update-manager:5052): Glib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
```

[Error while running update manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQMRK.png)

[output of sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8A40.png)

**Edit:** I am also getting errors when I run sudo ubuntu-support-staus. Error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 133, in <module>
    pkg.name, support_tag)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 49, in get_maintenance_status
    raise Exception("No date tag found")
Exception: No date tag found
```

Please help
Thanks :)

Comment: In terminal do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Please [edit] and post the error messages, if any, in its entirety.

Comment: I don't get any error messages by running these commands but the problem still persists

Comment: Did it installed any updates?

Comment: Sorry for the delay i have edited the question with some screenshots

Comment: No it doesn't install any updates

Comment: @CelticWarrior Please be sure to read up on the [Be Nice](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice) page, particularly the second bullet point about patience. Many people have busy lives and many responsibilities outside of Ask Ubuntu, and it makes this website a nicer place if we're all *exceedingly* patient with each other, assuming best intentions always :) Thank you for all you do to contribute to this community.

Comment: @NickWeinberg It took the OP ~4min to run apt-get and it would have been better to say right away *"(...) and no updates were installed." As such the delay seemed odd (but now I see it was entirely justified. I was only trying to avoid a tedious back'n'forth just to confirm the suspected **non-issue** .

Comment: @srijanbhatia No problem whatsoever, your system is fully updated. The error messages when running the update manager in terminal are typical of any graphical app being run that way and are meaningless.

Comment: @CelticWarrior thanks for your help. I am new to ubuntu and thought that might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

srijan,

Try running `sudo apt-get clean all`  followed by `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*` then proceed with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` . Something could be jacked due to a lock file or the cached files. Also make sure there are no other dpkg or apt processes running already before you start :)

Let us know.

Comment: Ran all these commands. Still no progress.

Comment: So..... I missed the last four posts above. CelticWarrior is right about running update-manager and ubuntu-support-status commands in that they are not relevant to what you really want is patches being applied to your machine.

Comment: Yeah I found a patch in this bug report [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-apt/+bug/1503979). Thanks for helping out